# Problemas con @inject en laravel 8.x

Tags: php, laravel

tengo el siguiente código insertado en la vista index.Blade.php

```
@inject( 'Familias' , 'App\HTMLElements\FamiliaHTMLElements.php' )
```

Envío fichero correspondiente a FamiliaHTMLElements.

```
namespace App\HTMLElements;

use App\Models\Familia;
use Illuminate\Support\HtmlString;


(1)class FamiliaHTMLElements
{


}
```

El código correspondiente a @inject ,en principio , debería llegar hasta el fichero FamiliaHTMLElements.php En su lugar se produce el siguiente error.

```
Target class [App\HTMLElements\FamiliaHTMLElements.php] does not exist. (View: 
C:\proyecto8\resources\views\backend\articulos\index.blade.php)
```

Y el fichero FamaliaHTMLElements contiene esa clase (1) ¿Dónde me equivoco? Gracias anticipadas.

Comment: No tienes que agregar el .php cuando invocas a la clase por su namespace quitalo y comenta

Comment: @BetaM Ok ahora accedo a la clase gracias

Comment: Dado eso entonces puedes responder tu propia pregunta